# Excel - Look through value for a particular column and paste in another sheet

Tags: excel

I have a column with cells value is either 1 or empty / 0

I want to loop through individual cell from B4 to B50 to check the value in this sheet called "Data".

If value is 1, then copy the cell content on the left (A4) to another sheet called "Main" at B2.
While copying, it need to check the cell (B2) is empty, if not, check next B3, B4 and paste to next empty cell.
Pasting into cell should retain the format of the words (e.g. Bold,italic, if there is) and colour of the cells that is copying from.

Then return to "Data" sheet and resume checkin for value 1. Loop until B50.

Appreciate using excel 2016 VBA. I tried a few type of codes but remain error.

Comment: Please post the codes which giving error.

Comment: u r looking for https://exceljet.net/index-and-match right ?